# ruby loop through data returned by API call

Tags: ruby, sinatra, plivo

I am working with ruby and sinatra. Using the Plivo api, I want to access the returned data, iterate through it and extract and print all the instances of some of the elements and print them out as HTML on my web page.

my ruby code is:

```
user_key = 'my_key'
 params = { 'account' => user_key }
 response = p.get_cdrs(params)
 obj = response.last.to_json
```

which gets the following returned in the Firebug console:

```
{
   "api_id":"c59f2008-5baf-11e3-bbb2-22000ac522d1",
   "meta":{
      "limit":20,
      "next":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/?account=MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD&limit=20&offset=20",
      "offset":0,
      "previous":null,
      "total_count":114
   },
   "objects":[
      {
         "bill_duration":21,
         "billed_duration":60,
         "call_direction":"outbound",
         "call_duration":21,
         "call_uuid":"103a3bc6-5baa-11e3-a878-f30f0e86751e",
         "end_time":"2013-12-03 08:33:44+09:00",
         "from_number":"85258081345",
         "parent_call_uuid":"0313c23c-5baa-11e3-a673-f30f0e86751e",
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/103a3bc6-5baa-11e3-a878-f30f0e86751e/",
         "to_number":"14157638148",
         "total_amount":"0.01200",
         "total_rate":"0.01200"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":21,
         "billed_duration":60,
         "call_direction":"inbound",
         "call_duration":21,
         "call_uuid":"0313c23c-5baa-11e3-a673-f30f0e86751e",
         "end_time":"2013-12-03 08:33:44+09:00",
         "from_number":"sip:hechan131129083410@phone.plivo.com",
         "parent_call_uuid":null,
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/0313c23c-5baa-11e3-a673-f30f0e86751e/",
         "to_number":"14157638148",
         "total_amount":"0.00300",
         "total_rate":"0.00300"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":358,
         "billed_duration":360,
         "call_direction":"inbound",
         "call_duration":358,
         "call_uuid":"0b07abb2-5b40-11e3-8fb1-057cf5362a5f",
         "end_time":"2013-12-02 19:59:58+09:00",
         "from_number":"441903773807",
         "parent_call_uuid":null,
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/0b07abb2-5b40-11e3-8fb1-057cf5362a5f/",
         "to_number":"441903337012",
         "total_amount":"0.04800",
         "total_rate":"0.00800"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":344,
         "billed_duration":360,
         "call_direction":"outbound",
         "call_duration":344,
         "call_uuid":"116d89f4-5b40-11e3-8fe5-057cf5362a5f",
         "end_time":"2013-12-02 19:59:57+09:00",
         "from_number":null,
         "parent_call_uuid":"0b07abb2-5b40-11e3-8fb1-057cf5362a5f",
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/116d89f4-5b40-11e3-8fe5-057cf5362a5f/",
         "to_number":"sip:niyan130903202713@phone.plivo.com",
         "total_amount":"0.01800",
         "total_rate":"0.00300"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":27,
         "billed_duration":60,
         "call_direction":"outbound",
         "call_duration":27,
         "call_uuid":"1b026a9a-5b3e-11e3-898e-1b5c95282229",
         "end_time":"2013-12-02 19:40:46+09:00",
         "from_number":"85258081345",
         "parent_call_uuid":"19f8572c-5b3e-11e3-8930-1b5c95282229",
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/1b026a9a-5b3e-11e3-898e-1b5c95282229/",
         "to_number":"441903773807",
         "total_amount":"0.01900",
         "total_rate":"0.01900"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":27,
         "billed_duration":60,
         "call_direction":"inbound",
         "call_duration":27,
         "call_uuid":"19f8572c-5b3e-11e3-8930-1b5c95282229",
         "end_time":"2013-12-02 19:40:46+09:00",
         "from_number":"sip:hechan131129083410@phone.plivo.com",
         "parent_call_uuid":null,
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/19f8572c-5b3e-11e3-8930-1b5c95282229/",
         "to_number":"441903773807",
         "total_amount":"0.00300",
         "total_rate":"0.00300"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":175,
         "billed_duration":180,
         "call_direction":"inbound",
         "call_duration":175,
         "call_uuid":"e59e46f6-5b3a-11e3-8488-1b5c95282229",
         "end_time":"2013-12-02 19:20:16+09:00",
         "from_number":"sip:hechan131129083410@phone.plivo.com",
         "parent_call_uuid":null,
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/e59e46f6-5b3a-11e3-8488-1b5c95282229/",
         "to_number":"441903773807",
         "total_amount":"0.00900",
         "total_rate":"0.00300"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":175,
         "billed_duration":180,
         "call_direction":"outbound",
         "call_duration":175,
         "call_uuid":"e698b528-5b3a-11e3-84e1-1b5c95282229",
         "end_time":"2013-12-02 19:20:16+09:00",
         "from_number":"85258081345",
         "parent_call_uuid":"e59e46f6-5b3a-11e3-8488-1b5c95282229",
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/e698b528-5b3a-11e3-84e1-1b5c95282229/",
         "to_number":"441903773807",
         "total_amount":"0.05700",
         "total_rate":"0.01900"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":728,
         "billed_duration":780,
         "call_direction":"outbound",
         "call_duration":728,
         "call_uuid":"b421ca72-5b34-11e3-82c5-1b5c95282229",
         "end_time":"2013-12-02 18:45:04+09:00",
         "from_number":"85258081345",
         "parent_call_uuid":"b3210c64-5b34-11e3-8250-1b5c95282229",
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/b421ca72-5b34-11e3-82c5-1b5c95282229/",
         "to_number":"85265001927",
         "total_amount":"0.33800",
         "total_rate":"0.02600"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":728,
         "billed_duration":780,
         "call_direction":"inbound",
         "call_duration":728,
         "call_uuid":"b3210c64-5b34-11e3-8250-1b5c95282229",
         "end_time":"2013-12-02 18:45:04+09:00",
         "from_number":"sip:hechan131129083410@phone.plivo.com",
         "parent_call_uuid":null,
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/b3210c64-5b34-11e3-8250-1b5c95282229/",
         "to_number":"85265001927",
         "total_amount":"0.03900",
         "total_rate":"0.00300"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":800,
         "billed_duration":840,
         "call_direction":"outbound",
         "call_duration":800,
         "call_uuid":"49c4bc6a-5b30-11e3-aa2e-f30f0e86751e",
         "end_time":"2013-12-02 18:14:41+09:00",
         "from_number":"85258081345",
         "parent_call_uuid":"43465b3c-5b30-11e3-a842-f30f0e86751e",
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/49c4bc6a-5b30-11e3-aa2e-f30f0e86751e/",
         "to_number":"818042010550",
         "total_amount":"2.01600",
         "total_rate":"0.14400"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":800,
         "billed_duration":840,
         "call_direction":"inbound",
         "call_duration":800,
         "call_uuid":"43465b3c-5b30-11e3-a842-f30f0e86751e",
         "end_time":"2013-12-02 18:14:41+09:00",
         "from_number":"sip:hechan131129083410@phone.plivo.com",
         "parent_call_uuid":null,
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/43465b3c-5b30-11e3-a842-f30f0e86751e/",
         "to_number":"818042010550",
         "total_amount":"0.04200",
         "total_rate":"0.00300"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":2,
         "billed_duration":60,
         "call_direction":"outbound",
         "call_duration":2,
         "call_uuid":"7f1db12e-5a7b-11e3-9c03-c7a22946c980",
         "end_time":"2013-12-01 20:27:08+09:00",
         "from_number":"185258081345",
         "parent_call_uuid":"7e6225d0-5a7b-11e3-9bd4-c7a22946c980",
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/7f1db12e-5a7b-11e3-9c03-c7a22946c980/",
         "to_number":"sip:hechan131129083410@phone.plivo.com",
         "total_amount":"0.00300",
         "total_rate":"0.00300"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":2,
         "billed_duration":60,
         "call_direction":"inbound",
         "call_duration":2,
         "call_uuid":"7e6225d0-5a7b-11e3-9bd4-c7a22946c980",
         "end_time":"2013-12-01 20:27:08+09:00",
         "from_number":"185258081345",
         "parent_call_uuid":null,
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/7e6225d0-5a7b-11e3-9bd4-c7a22946c980/",
         "to_number":"14154292111",
         "total_amount":"0.00850",
         "total_rate":"0.00850"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":1628,
         "billed_duration":1680,
         "call_direction":"outbound",
         "call_duration":1628,
         "call_uuid":"108c1c14-5a76-11e3-a749-1b5c95282229",
         "end_time":"2013-12-01 20:15:25+09:00",
         "from_number":"85258081345",
         "parent_call_uuid":"0f78d9c0-5a76-11e3-a6af-1b5c95282229",
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/108c1c14-5a76-11e3-a749-1b5c95282229/",
         "to_number":"441903773807",
         "total_amount":"0.53200",
         "total_rate":"0.01900"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":1628,
         "billed_duration":1680,
         "call_direction":"inbound",
         "call_duration":1628,
         "call_uuid":"0f78d9c0-5a76-11e3-a6af-1b5c95282229",
         "end_time":"2013-12-01 20:15:25+09:00",
         "from_number":"sip:hechan131129083410@phone.plivo.com",
         "parent_call_uuid":null,
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/0f78d9c0-5a76-11e3-a6af-1b5c95282229/",
         "to_number":"441903773807",
         "total_amount":"0.08400",
         "total_rate":"0.00300"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":57,
         "billed_duration":60,
         "call_direction":"outbound",
         "call_duration":57,
         "call_uuid":"ce7f25f6-5a6f-11e3-ae45-f30f0e86751e",
         "end_time":"2013-12-01 19:04:37+09:00",
         "from_number":"85258081345",
         "parent_call_uuid":"c938e38e-5a6f-11e3-aca3-f30f0e86751e",
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/ce7f25f6-5a6f-11e3-ae45-f30f0e86751e/",
         "to_number":"441903773807",
         "total_amount":"0.01900",
         "total_rate":"0.01900"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":57,
         "billed_duration":60,
         "call_direction":"inbound",
         "call_duration":57,
         "call_uuid":"c938e38e-5a6f-11e3-aca3-f30f0e86751e",
         "end_time":"2013-12-01 19:04:37+09:00",
         "from_number":"sip:hechan131129083410@phone.plivo.com",
         "parent_call_uuid":null,
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/c938e38e-5a6f-11e3-aca3-f30f0e86751e/",
         "to_number":"441903773807",
         "total_amount":"0.00300",
         "total_rate":"0.00300"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":126,
         "billed_duration":180,
         "call_direction":"outbound",
         "call_duration":126,
         "call_uuid":"24ed88a4-5a59-11e3-a462-fdc08976d83f",
         "end_time":"2013-12-01 16:23:39+09:00",
         "from_number":"185258081345",
         "parent_call_uuid":"2445b890-5a59-11e3-a437-fdc08976d83f",
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/24ed88a4-5a59-11e3-a462-fdc08976d83f/",
         "to_number":"818088931617",
         "total_amount":"0.43200",
         "total_rate":"0.14400"
      },
      {
         "bill_duration":126,
         "billed_duration":180,
         "call_direction":"inbound",
         "call_duration":126,
         "call_uuid":"2445b890-5a59-11e3-a437-fdc08976d83f",
         "end_time":"2013-12-01 16:23:39+09:00",
         "from_number":"185258081345",
         "parent_call_uuid":null,
         "resource_uri":"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/2445b890-5a59-11e3-a437-fdc08976d83f/",
         "to_number":"14154292111",
         "total_amount":"0.02550",
         "total_rate":"0.00850"
      }
   ]
}
```

sorry it is so long.

Now, I want to access certain parts of the data and print out as HTML, for example, all the bill_durations and all the call_directions. How can I do this?

When I try:

```
obj.each do |row|
   bill_duration = ob["objects"][0]["bill_duration"]
  halt 200, { :bill_duration => bill_duration }
  end
```

the heroku error is:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `each' for #<String:0x007f82e6448b38>
```

What's wrong here? Thanks guys!

OK, here is what I have now:

```
response.last['objects'].each do |row| 
 bill_duration = row["bill_duration"] 
 halt 200,  { :bill_duration => bill_duration }.to_json 
 end
```

this does not produce an error but it only returns one record despite the loop. I need to get all the instances of bill_duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with assistance from Peter Alfvin, the sanswer is:

```
results =  response.last['objects'].each do |row| 
  bill_duration = row["bill_duration"]
  { :bill_duration => bill_duration }
  end
 halt 200,  results.to_json 
 end
```

then can be accessed and printed out, with jQuery, as follows:

```
$.getJSON("/callrecords", function(data) {
        $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
        var txt = '<p>' +this["bill_duration"]+ '</p>';
      $(".results").append(txt);
     });//end each
    });//end JSON
```

Brilliant, I have been struggling with this, on and off, for ages. Thank you Peter!!

Comment: Given that I answered your question about the error and provided additional assistance through comments, I was really surprised to see you "unaccept" my answer. At the very least, I think an "upvote" would be in order at this point. Besides, us older guys need to support each other. ;-) (I noticed we're the same age).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `.to_json` generates a *string*, not a hash, which is why you're getting the error your getting. It's informally documented at http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Generating+JSON

You can turn that string back into an object with `JSON.parse` or you can operate on `response.last` directly. In either case, though, note that the object is going be a *hash*, not an array, so you'll have to select the `objects` element from it before you can start iterating through the objects array, as in:

```
response.last['objects'].each
```

or

```
JSON.parse(obj)['objects'].each
```

Comment: thanks. Here is what I have now: response.last['objects'].each do |row|
  bill_duration = row["objects"][0]["bill_duration"]
  halt 200, { :bill_duration => bill_duration }.to_json
  end and the error is NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass:
I am really stuck!

Comment: `row[objects]` is a hash, not an array. `row[objects][0]` is `nil`, giving you the error. Get rid of the `[0]`

Comment: Also, you should update your question with the modified code/results, as you can't really read code in comments due to the lack of line breaks. Alternatively, use semicolons to separate lines in the comment.

Comment: thank you, still stuck but making progress. Please see above.